# React cannot set variable inside onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to set a variable inside an onClick event. I am setting the error messages into the variable.

```
const handleEdit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

         if (edit_user.email == "") {
             setEditUserError({ email: "Please enter an email!" })
        }

        if (edit_user.company == "") {
           setEditUserError({ ...edit_user_error, company: "Please enter company!" })
       }
```

And I am showing the error in the form like `<span className="text-danger">{edit_user_error.company}</span>`

The problem is that when all the fields are empty and when I click the button only the last message is shown. When I make one field empty, and then click the submit button it is working correctly. I tried `console.log(edit_user_error)` but it is showing empty. What am I doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React state updates are async, which means they won't run right away. So when running multiple `setState` to the same state, you can't expect the state from the first `setState` call to be update it before the second `setState` call happens.

In short, React is ignoring your earlier `setState` calls because they happen one after another.

The solution is to put the update into a single call:

```js
    const handleEdit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
         
        let errors = {};

         if (edit_user.email == "") {
             errors.email = "Please enter an email!"
        }

        if (edit_user.company == "") {
           errors.company = "Please enter company!"
       }

      // and then we call state with all the values, only once
      setEditUserError(errors);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because of batched state updates. React will try to reduce the renders by minimizing the state updates. You can use functional state update to fix this:

```
if (edit_user.email == "") {
  setEditUserError({ email: "Please enter an email!" });
}

if (edit_user.company == "") {
  // this callback gets executed only when previous state updates are done
  setEditUserError((prev) => ({ ...prev, company: "Please enter company!" }));
}
```

To clear the errors when fields are valid:

```
const getErrors = () => {
  return {
    ...(!edit_user.email ? { email: "Please enter an email!" } : {}),
    ...(!edit_user.company ? { company: "Please enter company!" } : {}),
  };
};

const handleEdit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  setEditUserError(getErrors());
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly. When I enter values and submit, the error messages are not going.

Comment: @Akhilesh That's because there's no code to clear the errors if the fields are valid. Not exactly related to the original problem. Anyway updated the answer to clear the errors.